# UDP Client Server dual communication

Tags: java, networking, udp

I am learning about  [UDP client server](http://www.techdive.in/java/java-socket-programming-user-datagram-protocol-udp) where the communication is one way from Server to Client. Server will send UDP packets to Client.

I want to to make it dual communication where Server and Client can send UDP packets to each other.

Do I need to make another Datagram socket for Client Server to make it dual communication or can I use my existing Datagram socket to do the job. If I dont need another Datagram Socket , I would appreciate if you can show me how it is done

I would appreciate if you can point me to relevant resources on dual commuication for Client Server

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can use the existing DatagramSocket.

Take a look at example in this link:
 http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/s2011/cs325/feb25.html

Its upon you how to use the **send** and **receive** methods of a socket depending on your needs.